# How to transfer all settings to a new installation?

Tags: system-installation

I want my install my ubuntu installation in a dedicated hard drive instead of a partition. I am thinking about doing a fresh 14.04 install on this empty hard drive. How can I transfer my settings so, I don't have to reinstall everything and setup everything again?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, an upgrade will only keep the personal files like music and documents but the system wide settings will be cleared.
A clean install is default settings and so any settings you had previously is obviously gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all your personal settings in your home folder by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (this will show all hidden files and folders, ie with names that start with a `.`) Copy all those folders that start with dot (for example `.config .firefox .icons .themes` etc) and paste them to your new home folder. Don't forget to also make a backup of all your home files like music. Sorry for my bad English level...I’m learning English as second language.